# how can I align the labels & inputs to the right

Tags: html, css

how can I align the labels & inputs to the right
like that all of then appear in the same line

```css
.radioContainer{
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioContainer" style="margin-bottom: 40px; margin-right: 0px; ">
    <label class="title" for="">fav food</label>
        <label for="burger">burger</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="burger">
        <br>
        <label for="fries">fries</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fries">
        <br>
        <label for="onionRings">onion rings</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="onionRings">
        <br>
        <label for="cackes">cakes</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cackes" >

    <small></small>
</div>
```

Comment: `width: fit-content` I advise to use with a prefix

Comment: do you mean all elements stay at the same line aligned to right? or you want each (`label` + `input`) stay at the same line but aligned to right?

Answer (score 0):

To have them in the same line, I would start by removing `<br />` from your code. Then set the css for input and label to be `inline-block`, something like:

```css
.radioContainer{
   width: fit-content;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

label, input { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="radioContainer" style="margin-bottom: 40px; margin-right: 0px; ">
   <label class="title" for="">fav food</label>
   <label for="burger">burger</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="burger">
    
   <label for="fries">fries</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="fries">
  
   <label for="onionRings">onion rings</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="onionRings">
  
   <label for="cackes">cakes</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="cackes" >
   <small></small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make all inputs inline, just remove all the `<br />` tags.

Example:

```
<div class="radioContainer" style="margin-bottom: 40px; margin-right: 0px; ">
  <label class="title" for="">fav food</label>
  <label for="burger">burger</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="burger">
  <label for="fries">fries</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="fries">
  <label for="onionRings">onion rings</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="onionRings">
  <label for="cackes">cakes</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cackes">
  <small></small>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/jOMeqex

Answer (score 0):

I understood your Question that you want them still below each other but aligned to the right side. So i made a solution using flexbox instead of the hard breaks. I commented the Code where i made changes and why, html and css.

Basically i used a colum and put each item-combination (label and checkbox)in a new row-div.

```css
.radioContainer{
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    /*make item a flexbox-container*/
    display: flex;
    /*combination of flex-direction and flex-wrap*/
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.row{
  /*make item a flexboc container*/
  display: flex;
  /*flex-flow: row nowrap; this is the default value of flex, which is why you dont need it,
just wanted to leave it in as a comment so you know whats happening*/
  /*Align the contents on the end of each row*/
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioContainer" style="margin-bottom: 40px; margin-right: 0px; ">
   <!--removed the hard breaks and added row-divs around each item combination-->
   <div class="row">
      <label class="title" for="">fav food</label>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <label for="burger">burger</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="burger">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <label for="fries">fries</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="fries">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <label for="onionRings">onion rings</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="onionRings">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <label for="cackes">cakes</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="cackes" >
   </div>
   <small></small>
</div>
```